Cancelling All Tasks on Failure with `concurrent.futures` in Python
I am using Python's concurrent.futures library with ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor. I want to implement a mechanism to cancel all running or unexecuted tasks if any one of the tasks fails. Specifically, I want to:

Cancel all futures (both running and unexecuted) when a task fails.
Raise the error that caused the first task to fail if that error is silently ignored; otherwise, let Python raise it naturally.

Here is the approach I have tried:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from functools import partial

copy_func = partial(copy_from, table_name=table_name, column_string=column_string)
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cores_to_use) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(copy_func, file_path): file_path for file_path in file_path_list}
    for f in as_completed(futures):
        try:
            f.result()
        except Exception as e:
            executor.shutdown(wait=False)  # Attempt to stop the executor
            for future in futures:
                future.cancel()  # Cancel all futures
            raise e  # Raise the exception

Questions:

Is this the correct way to handle task cancellation in ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor?
Are there any better approaches to achieve this functionality?
How can I ensure that the raised exception is not silently ignored?
How can I free up all resources used by concurrent.futures after an exception?

Thank you!

Is this the correct way to handle task cancellation in ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor?
Your approach is almost correct, but there are some important things to note:

executor.shutdown(wait=False) only prevents new tasks from being submitted. It doesn't actually cancel the running tasks. The tasks that have already started executing will continue until completion.
future.cancel() only cancels tasks that are still in the queue (not started). If a task has already started, future.cancel() won't stop it.

To cancel the running tasks effectively, you need to handle it in a way that your tasks can be interrupted by checking a flag or catching an exception.
Are there any better approach to achieve this functionality?
A better approach would be to use a combination of:

Graceful task cancellation: Your tasks should periodically check for a flag or signal to cancel themselves.
handling exceptions properly: You can use a try/except block with the worker function(copy_from) itself to detect failure and propagate it.

Here's the code:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from functools import partial
import threading

# Cancellation event that worker tasks can check
cancel_event = threading.Event()

def copy_from(file_path, table_name, column_string):
    if cancel_event.is_set():
        print(f"Task {file_path} cancelled.")
        return
    # Simulate some work or copying logic
    try:
        # Your actual copy operation here
        if file_path == "some_bad_file":
            raise ValueError("Simulated task failure")
        print(f"Processing {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        cancel_event.set()  # Set the cancellation flag
        raise e

# Function to handle task execution
def run_tasks(file_path_list, table_name, column_string, cores_to_use):
    copy_func = partial(copy_from, table_name=table_name, column_string=column_string)

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cores_to_use) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(copy_func, file_path): file_path for file_path in file_path_list}

        try:
            for f in as_completed(futures):
                if cancel_event.is_set():
                    # If cancellation has been triggered, skip waiting for further results
                    break
                # Attempt to get the result and raise any exception if task failed
                f.result()
        except Exception as e:
            cancel_event.set()  # Cancel all tasks
            for future in futures:
                future.cancel()  # Attempt to cancel futures that haven't started yet
            raise e  # Re-raise the exception

file_path_list = ["file1", "file2", "some_bad_file", "file4"]
table_name = "my_table"
column_string = "col1, col2"

try:
    run_tasks(file_path_list, table_name, column_string, cores_to_use=4)
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"An error occurred: {ex}")

How can I ensure that the raised exception is not silently ignored?
To ensure that the exception is not silently ignored, it is critical to:

Always call f.result() in the for f in as_completed(futures) loop. This will raise any exceptions that occurred during task execution.
Propagate the exception using raise a after canceling other tasks, as you have done.

How can I free up all resources used by concurrent.futures after an exception?
By default, when the with ProcessPoolExecutor block exists, it calls executor.shutdown(), which releases resources. This is handled automatically by Python's context manager. However, adding executor.shutdown(wait=False) is unnecessary, as you don't need to prematurely shut down the executor if you've handled cancellation properly.
To ensure resources are properly cleaned:

Tasks that haven't started should be canceled with future.cancel().
Tasks that have already started will be stopped by setting the cancellation flag, and when all tasks finish, the context manager will clean up the pool and free up resources.

I hope this will help you a little.

Well, your code worked in ThreadPoolExecutor. But it gave me this error Exception has occurred: TypeError cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object when used in ProcessPoolExecutor.

You might want to take a look at the wait() function:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_EXCEPTION

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = {
        executor.submit(copy_func, file_path): file_path
        for file_path in file_path_list
    }
    results = wait(futures, FIRST_EXCEPTION)

# results.not_done is a set of futures that did not complete
# results.done is a set of futures that did complete,
# possibly including one with exception. The call to result()
# might trigger an exception
for future in results.done:
    future.result()

Please see documentation for the wait() function for more information.

When a process is terminated with a call to multiprocessing.Process.terminate() any child threads or processes the process had created in a multithreading or multiprocessing pool will terminate immediately also. The idea then is to run the pool in a child process (worker function child_process, for example) that sets an event to signal back to the main process when it wishes for the main process to terminate the child_process. This can be either when all submitted tasks have completed normally or when the first exception is detected.
Here's the general idea, which you can adapt for your particular needs:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from multiprocessing import Process, Event
import time


def worker(t):
    time.sleep(t)
    if t == 4:
        raise RuntimeError('Oops')
    print(t)

def child_process(completion_event):
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)
    futures = [
        pool.submit(worker, t) for t in (1, 3, 4, 7)
    ]
    try:
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            result = future.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        # Once the main process's wait on this event is
        # satisfied, it will terminate this child process:
        completion_event.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    completion_event = Event()
    p = Process(target=child_process, args=(completion_event,))
    p.start()
    completion_event.wait()
    p.terminate()

Prints:
1
3
Oops

